# Java:Counting the times each number is rolled on a die

Tags: java, random, numbers, die

```
public class Die {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random r = new Random();    

    int dieOne=0, dieTwo=0, dieThree=0, dieFour=0, dieFive=0, dieSix=0;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How many times would you like the die to roll?: ");
        int numRoll = input.nextInt();  

    for (int i=0; i < numRoll; i++) {
        int rNum=r.nextInt(6)+1;

        if (rNum==1); {
            dieOne++;
        } 
        if (rNum==2); {
            dieTwo++;
        }
        if (rNum==3); {
            dieThree++;
        }
        if (rNum==4); {
            dieFour++;
        }
        if (rNum==5); {
            dieFive++;
        }
        if (rNum==6); {
            dieSix++;
        }
        System.out.println("Number:" + rNum);
    }

    System.out.println("'1' was rolled:" + dieOne + "times.");
    System.out.println("'2' was rolled:" + dieTwo + "times.");
    System.out.println("'3' was rolled:" + dieThree + "times.");
    System.out.println("'4' was rolled:" + dieFour + "times.");
    System.out.println("'5' was rolled:" + dieFive + "times.");
    System.out.println("'6' was rolled:" + dieSix + "times.");
    }
}
```

So if I run the program and enter 2. I'll get this:

```
Number:6
Number:3
'1' was rolled:2times.
'2' was rolled:2times.
'3' was rolled:2times.
'4' was rolled:2times.
'5' was rolled:2times.
'6' was rolled:2times.
```

But my desired output is this:

```
Number:6
Number:3
'1' was rolled:0times.
'2' was rolled:0times.
'3' was rolled:1times.
'4' was rolled:0times.
'5' was rolled:0times.
'6' was rolled:1times.
```

Using this same method what is solution to this problem?

Comment: Lose those semicolons following your `if` conditions.

Comment: Thank you very much, I don't know how I didn't notice that.

Comment: Have you learned about arrays yet?

Comment: I would rather chose `switch` than `if` in this case.

Comment: @msagala25 An array would be much cleaner, and easier to extend or generalize for D&D players.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove those semicolons following the `if`

```
if (rNum==1) {
   dieOne++;
}
```

instead of

```
if (rNum==1); {
   dieOne++;
}
```

Also, you should use `else` branch or better use array to solve this sort of problem